# Exporting orders to CSV throws an error in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to export orders in Magento. However, after clicking "Export", I end up with an error "There has been an error processing your request". Details of this error:

```
{ 
   "0":"Path \"\/var\/www\/site.com\/var\/\" cannot be used with directory \"\/var\/www\/site.com\/var\/\"",
   "1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Directory\\Read->validatePath('\/var\/www\/site...', 'export') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Filesystem\/Directory\/Read.php:111]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Directory\\Read->getAbsolutePath('\/var\/www\/site...', 'export') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Filesystem\/Directory\/Write.php:57]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Directory\\Write->assertWritable('export') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Filesystem\/Directory\/Write.php:326]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Directory\\Write->openFile('export\/sales_ord...', 'w+') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Model\/Export\/ConvertToCsv.php:78]\n#5 Magento\\Ui\\Model\\Export\\ConvertToCsv->getCsvFile() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Export\/GridToCsv.php:70]\n#6 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php:231]\n#8 Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#9 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#10 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:143]\n#11 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor#00000000716f84130000000018abcb9a#, &Closure#00000000716f84110000000018abcb9a#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#12 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#13 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Ui\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Export\/GridToCsv\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#14 Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#, &Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor#00000000716f84130000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:99]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000716f87250000000018abcb9a#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:258]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000716f87da0000000018abcb9a#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>",
   "url":"\/admin\/mui\/export\/gridToCsv\/key\/2b2173b953f4d2edc5e9246b4f975041d5679d9a2796caae745fda18dbe4cd99\/?filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&search=&namespace=sales_order_grid&selected%5B%5D=47",
   "script_name":"\/index.php"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was only related to permissions issues.

```
cd <Magento install directory> && \
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && \
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && \
sudo chown -R :<web server group> . && \
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Many thanks! Looks like I had wrong permissions on var folder. This solved my issue:
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;